# cordova run wp8 on device not working

Tags: node.js, cordova, windows-phone-8

Hello I'm trying to run my application on windows phone.

Therefore I use:

```
cordova run wp8 --device
```

But I get this error:

`ERROR: Error code -2146233087 for command: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs \Windows Phone\v8.0\Tools\Xap Deployment\XapDeployCmd.exe with args: /installlau nch,C:/pathToProject/platforms/wp8/Bin/debug/CordovaAppProj_Debug _AnyCPU.xap,/targetdevice:de ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: C:\pathToProject\platforms\wp8\cordova\run.bat: Command failed with exit code 2 You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project`

I'm using cordova 5.0.0, ionic 1.4.5 and npm version 1.4.28 and I am on a windows 8.1 pro 64 bit.

I've googled around but couldn't find any working solution on this.